# I don`t understand how 'waitForReadyRead()' actually works

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcpsocket

I am new to Qt and I am just experimentig with the network framework

There is one thing I don't understand when using `waitForReadyRead()` and `readLine()` with a `QTcpSocket`.

The following code is supposed to read 3 lines of text from a server.

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])    {

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket ();
    socket->connectToHost("Localhost",8888);
    
    //when connected,  server sends first line of text
    if (socket->waitForConnected(1000)) {
        std::cout << "Connected\n";
    }

    //Server sends two more lines of text after receiving 'Hello'
    socket->write("Hello\n");  
    socket->waitForBytesWritten(1000); `

    int cnt = 0;
    
    while (cnt < 7) {
        
        //if (cnt == 5) //<- uncomment to use waitforReadyRead in round 6 only 
        socket->waitForReadyRead(1); // <- without this, only first line of text is printed
        
        std::cout << " Round " << cnt+1 << " : ";

        if (socket->canReadLine()) {
            std::cout << socket->bytesAvailable() << "  Bytes Available. ";
            std::cout << "Reading: " << socket->readLine(1024).toStdString();
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
        cnt++;
    }
 return a.exec();
 }
```

When I use `socket->waitForReadyRead(1);` in the `while` loop, I get the correct output:

**Connected**
**Round 1 : 68  Bytes Available. Reading: 1234567**
**Round 2 : 59  Bytes Available. Reading: 12345679012456789012345678901234567890**
**Round 3 : 17  Bytes Available. Reading: 123456789012345**
**Round 4 :**
**Round 5 :**
**Round 6 :**
**Round 7 :**

But if I DON'T use `socket->waitForReadyRead(1);` in the `while` loop, only the first line is printed:

**Connected**
**Round 1 : 9  Bytes Available. Reading: 1234567**
**Round 2 :**
**Round 3 :**
**Round 4 :**
**Round 5 :**
**Round 6 :**
**Round 7 :**

Another strange thing is, that when I use `socket->waitForReadyRead(1);` for example only in round 6, then all lines will be printed but the second and third line of text are printed in round 6 and 7, respectively:

**Connected**
**Round 1 : 9  Bytes Available. Reading: 1234567**

**Round 2 :**
**Round 3 :**
**Round 4 :**
**Round 5 :**
**Round 6 : 59  Bytes Available. Reading: 12345679012456789012345678901234567890**

**Round 7 : 17  Bytes Available. Reading: 123456789012345**

I simply don't understand the behaviour of `waitForReadyRead()`.
In the documentation there is given, that `waitForReadyRead()` only indicates that there is new data available. So in my case it actually shouldn't make a difference if I use `waitForReadyRead()` as all three lines of text should be already available for reading when entering the while loop (as it can be seen from the first example)!
Or am I getting something wrong here and it is necessary to call `waitForReadyRead()` every single time before reading datas from the device.

By the way, it doesn't matter if I use `waitForReadyRead()` with 1, 1000 or 3000 ms of waiting time.

Comment: Note that Qt's socket has a quirk where if it is not associated with an event handler, the `waitForReadyRead` function will actually perform the work of receiving data from the socket's reception buffer.

Comment: **How do you know** that 3 lines of text are available for reading when entering the while loop? The first example **waits** for them to become available? They might not be available when the loop starts!

Comment: @user253751: because I have also tried it with a pause right before entering the while loop using  `QThread::msleep(10000);`